# JUnit testing using powerMockito is giving NPE

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I Have a class for which i want to write a Junit unit test case.

```
public class ComparatorUtil {

    public static Map<String, ValueDifference<Object>> compareJsonObject(Object srcObject, Object targetObject)
                throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String initialJson = ConverterUtil.convertObjectToJson(srcObject);
        String updatedJson = ConverterUtil.convertObjectToJson(targetObject);
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(initialJson, mapType);
        Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(updatedJson, mapType);
        Map<String, MapDifference.ValueDifference<Object>> diffMap = Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap).entriesDiffering();
        return diffMap;
    }
}


public class ConverterUtil {

    public static String convertObjectToJson(Object o)
            throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapperObj.writeValueAsString(o);
    }
}
```

Junit test case written by me:-

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ConverterUtil.class)
public class ComparatorUtilTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConverterUtil.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testValueDiff() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        TestObject srcObject = new TestObject();
        srcObject.setColor("white");
        srcObject.setId(1);
        TestObject targetObj = new TestObject();
        targetObj.setColor("white");
        targetObj.setId(1);
        targetObj.setSuffix("AA");
        ComparatorUtil.compareJsonObject(srcObject, targetObj);
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(VerificationModeFactory.times(2));
        ConverterUtil.convertObjectToJson(srcObject);
        ConverterUtil.convertObjectToJson(targetObj);
    }
}
```

When I am running the test class, I am getting a `Null Pointer Exception` as the `initialJson` and `updatedJson` is coming to be null. Can anyone please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer ... and even when you don't want to accept the answer (although 10 years of experience tell me that it is the *correct* answer), consider at least to upvote, as I put serious energy in giving you the information you need.

Comment: @GhostCat : Thanks i appreciate your help. I have upvoted your answer not sure if it will reflect publicly as i do not much points on SO.

Comment: Some more now :-)... And as said: you can use PowerMock as well. But in order to tell you exactly why your code isn't working, we need a true [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

So many things so wrong here.

- You seem to *assume* how to use PowerMock. But what you put together simply doesn't make sense! You need to create a *mocking specification* using 'when().thenReturn()' for example.
- Meaning: it is not enough to instruct PowerMock that a certain class will be mocked. You have to tell PowerMock about the actual values to be returned when these static methods are invoked.
- so start by reading a good tutorial top to bottom. Don't use PowerMock for your own code, instead look how a tutorial solves a simple problem.

Then: PowerMock comes at certain cost. So you avoid using it. You rather should step back and look into reworking your code so that it can be tested without the need to mock static methods. You see, we are talking about code that transforms some input into some output. You should be able to write production and test code that requires no mocking at all for such situations. If at all, you should use frameworks such as Mockito - good production code can be tested without PowerMock.

More specifically: why is there a need to *mock* the static method? That seems to indicate that your ObjectMapper doesn't work in your unit test setup. It starts right there!

You see, a *good* unit test for your conversion method should simply look like:

```
assertThat(someConverterUnderTest.convert(fineTunedInput), is(expectedOutput));
```

That's it! You should design your converter to fully work in your unit test environment. And then all need for **mocks** is **gone**. In other words: you are currently testing *implementation details*. Instead you should always try testing the *public contract* of your methods. Testing implementation details is sometimes unavoidable, but as written before: the code you are showing here should really really be tested without mocks.

Then: even when you need mocks: the *static* methods are getting in your way. That is a clear signal that you shouldn't be using *static* here! Instead, you turn those elements that might require mocking either into parameters or into fields of your classes under test. Because then you can simply *inject* mocked objects. Which means that you don't need the PowerMock(ito) tooling anymore.

Comment: I have already written the unit test cases for ConverterUtil.java class.. So do i need to again test the values returned by ConverterUtil.convertObjectToJson(obj)?? I believe no..What i am trying to test here is if  ComparatorUtil.compareJsonObject(srcObject, targetObj) method is called then  ConverterUtil.convertObjectToJson(srcObject) method should be called twice...Please let me know if u have a better way to writing junit test case for this scenerio??

Comment: And yes i would also be writing a test case to assert the value returned by compareJsonObject() method.